# Initialize instance variable to specific column attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I apologize if my title a is a bit confusing... I'm not sure how else to phrase it.

Right now I have an "Exercise" model that has a column "muscle_group", with possible values "Abdominals", "Arms", "Back", "Chest", etc.
I want to use ActiveRecord to be able to group each row into an instance variable by muscle_group.

I currently have:

```
@abdominals = Exercise.where(:muscle_group => "Abdominals")
@arms = Exercise.where(:muscle_group => "Arms")
@back = Exercise.where(:muscle_group => "Back")
@chest = Exercise.where(:muscle_group => "Chest")
@legs = Exercise.where(:muscle_group => "Legs")
@shoulders = Exercise.where(:muscle_group => "Shoulders")
@ALL_EXERCISES = [@abdominals, @arms, @back, @chest, @legs, @shoulders]
```

in my controller. However, this does not seem DRY enough and it feels like I could do better.

I also have a model "Ex_Sets" that belongs_to "Exercise", which in return "has_many" "Ex_sets". In my view I have:

```
    -@ALL_EXERCISES.each do |mgroup|
      -if mgroup.present?
          %h2
            #{mgroup.first.muscle_group}
          -mgroup.each do |exercise|
            %p
                %h5
                  #{exercise.name}
                %h6
                  - exercise.ex_sets.each do |data|
                    %p
                      Sets: #{data.sets}
                      Reps: #{data.reps}
                      Weight: #{data.weight} lbs
```

to iterate through the @ALL_EXERCISES array I created earlier, which then iterates through each specific muscle group, which then iterates again to get all "Ex_Set" data. This hardly seems optimal, but I am not sure how to improve on this because I have never done much optimization.

My questions:

1) How can I dry up my code?

2) How can I optimize it instead of having 3 loops (O(n^3) I presume?)

Comment: I don't know how related this is but if you wanted @all_exercises to not be grouped, you could then flatten it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up figuring things out... For anybody who might be interested:

```
@all_exercises = Exercise.all.includes(:ex_sets).group_by(&:muscle_group)
```

to dry out my code. The

```
includes(:ex_sets)
```

uses eager loading to avoid unnecessary queries. 
As for optimizing my views, apparently 3 nested for loops does not necessary mean O(n^3) run time. It runs in O(n) and I've been told there's not much I can do to optimize its algorithmic efficiency. I can, however, use collection partials to clean my code:

http://robots.thoughtbot.com/rendering-collections-in-rails

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you can dry your controller code using grouping http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#group

Comment: Thanks, doing `@all_exercises = @exercises.group_by(&:muscle_group)` did the trick for me! The triple loop still bugs me though.